# dl, dt. dd for multiple list data

Tags: html

As from the [tutorial here](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2009/05/13/how-to-use-dl-dt-and-dd-html-tags-to-list-data-vs-table-list-data/), I can see that this is a valid markup dl, dt, dd structure,

```
<dl>
    <dt>Name: </dt>
    <dd>John Don</dd>

    <dt>Age: </dt>
    <dd>23</dd>

    <dt>Gender: </dt>
    <dd>Male</dd>

    <dt>Day of Birth:</dt>
    <dd>12th May 1986</dd>
</dl>
```

but this only structure for a single person, what about multiple people/ persons? What about this below? I want to have a header and then followed by a list of items,

```
<dl class="name-header">
    <dt>Name: </dt>
    <dt>Age: </dt> 
    <dt>Gender: </dt> 
    <dt>Day of Birth:</dt>
</dl>

<dl class="person-item">
    <dd>John Don</dd>
    <dd>23</dd>
    <dd>Male</dd>
    <dd>12th May 1986</dd>
</dl>

<dl class="person-item">
    <dd>John Don</dd>
    <dd>23</dd>
    <dd>Male</dd>
    <dd>12th May 1986</dd>
</dl>
```

Thanks.

**EDIT:**
[image]

Comment: what is stopping you from doing the later?

Comment: Thank God the tutorial is not [W3 Schools](http://www.w3fools.com) `:)`

Comment: I am not sure whether it is a valid structure or not...

Comment: See here for HTML structure validity: http://vidasp.net/HTML-structure-diagram.html

Comment: There's a tag called `dl-dt-dd`? With 11 questions? Really?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider a table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name:</th>
        <th>Age:</th>
        <th>Gender:</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>John Don</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>Male</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>John Don II</td>
        <td>53</td>
        <td>Male</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @lauthiamkok - err why not? then use `<div>`s

Comment: @lauthiamkok What layout do you want to achieve?

Comment: @lauthiamkok: I don't see how that can't be implemented with a table. In fact, it's certainly meant to be a table, not a definition list.

Comment: @Šime: you are right. I am using a table now which makes more sense! lol thanks.

Comment: This is a perfect example of when to actually use a TABLE. A table is for columns and rows of logically-related data, which this is.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, using the  tages the way you have BREAKS the semantic meaning.

With the markup below, it's obvious that 23 refers to the subject's age:

```
<dl>
   <dt>Name:</dt>
   <dd>John Don</dd>

   <dt>Age:</dt>
   <dd>23</dd>

   <dt>Birth Date:</dt>
   <dd>May 24 1967</dd>
</dl>
```

With your markup, it really isn't easy to tell:

```
<dl class="name-header">      
  <dt>Name: </dt>      
  <dt>Age: </dt>       
  <dt>Gender: </dt>       
  <dt>Day of Birth:</dt>      
</dl>          

<dl class="person-item">      
  <dd>John Don</dd>      
  <dd>23</dd>      
  <dd>Male</dd>      
  <dd>12th May 1986</dd>      
</dl>      

<dl class="person-item">      
   <dd>John Don</dd>      
   <dd>23</dd>      
   <dd>Male</dd>      
   <dd>12th May 1986</dd>      
</dl>
```

Answer (score 0):

The one below seems to be valid according to the spec, since neither a `dd` nor a `dt` is mandated; nevertheless I second the table proposal, as you will have less trouble keeping the headers and the content together.